# C# removing string before/after delimiter

Tags: c#, regex, string

I've seen a lot of post using RegEx to remove part of string before or after using some delimiter. The fact is, I don't understand RegEx and have a case a little strange. Here is the situation :

I have a string that can be :

```
string test1 = (something)...keepThisOne
string test2 = keepThisOne...(something)
string test3 = (something)...keepThisOne...(somethingelse)
```

So far I got :

```
string test = testx.Substring(testx.LastIndexOf('.')+1);
```

but it does not work even for the string test1

I know RegExp can be use to remove everything between paranthesis and all the "..." in this string. My question is how can I achieve that with RegExp without knowing in advance what kind of string test I will get, and what does it the RegExp means ??

The output needed is the get only :

```
string result = keepThisOne
```

whatever the string test is used.

Comment: What is your expected results for those exactly?

Comment: if you are using test1 what is the expected output string?

Comment: @SonerGönül as I said remove everything except the keepThisOne (I don't know the length of the string or what is Inside, only that the format of the string is one the the test1, 2 or 3).

Comment: so if you are processing `(something)....` output should be`something`??

Comment: @akhilkumar nop the output should be keepThisOne. everything else should be remove. I'll Edit the question so there is no confusion

Comment: so remove everything from first `.`?

Comment: Let's say you have test1 and test2. How do you know which one to keep? Because in test1 you keep everything before "..." and in test2 you keep everything after it. Is there anything special about "keepThisOne"?

Comment: KeepThisOne is the word I need to keep whatever the situation I got (whatever the string I recieve (test 1,2 and 3 are all the configuration that can happen))

Comment: Can you write an actual example of 2 strings, because we can't understand the formatting? I understand that you want to keep the string part "keepThisOne", but I don't know what it looks like, or what every other string looks like. If the string is "asdfasdfsadf...dsfasdfsdfas" which one do you keep? Are the other strings (those that you throw away), always inside parentheses?

Comment: @K.Gkinis yes the part I want to throw away is always Inside parenthèses and I need to remove the dots "...". This configuration can happen just like my exemple is already written;

Comment: Raidri 's answer should work then. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Slayner: try [`Regex.Replace(str, @"(?:\([^()]*\))?\.{3}(?:\([^()]*\))?", "")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a%5c(%5b%5e()%5d*%5c))%3f%5c.%7b3%7d(%3f%3a%5c(%5b%5e()%5d*%5c))%3f&i=(something)...keepThisOne%0d%0akeepThisOne...(something)%0d%0a(something)...keepThisOne...(somethingelse)&r=).

Comment: @stribizhev no overload methode for replace take 3 arguments

Comment: @stribizhev  I modified it so it is like test.Replace(@"(?:\([^()]*\))?\.{3}(?:\([^()]*\))?", ""), as I can see on RegExp Storm it worked fine but on my try it did nothing.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("(something)...keepThisOne", @"(?:\([^()]*\))?\.{3}(?:\([^()]*\))?", string.Empty));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code (adapted from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34156506/1892179)):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"…*\.*\(\w*\)\.*…*");
        Console.WriteLine(rgx.Replace("(something)…keepThisOne", string.Empty));
        Console.WriteLine(rgx.Replace("keepThisOne…(something)", string.Empty));
        Console.WriteLine(rgx.Replace("(something)...keepThisOne…(somethingelse)", string.Empty));

    }
}
```

Try it in a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Ayow8).

Comment: see the comment on stribizhev's answer. It's like he does not understand they are dots even when he show them.

Comment: @Slayner try my answer now.

Comment: Dude that's it, thanks a lot, thanks all of you that helped me.

Answer (score 3):

Try with Regex :

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\.*\(\w*\)\.*");
string result = rgx.Replace(input, string.Empty);
```

Regex will generate the output as

> keepThisOne
>   keepThisOne
>   keepThisOne

You can run the various scenario in [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/buGGDP) fiddle.

Comment: I have a good news and a bad news. The RegEx correctly removed everything Inside parenthese, but kept the "..."

Comment: I tried adding a Replace(".", string.Empty); after getting the string without the parenthèses and what is Inside. But it did not work, it's like he do not understand that they are dots in this string even when he show them

Comment: The fiddle, as it is, works. Care to show us exactly what input string you're testing? Maybe you have something that's not really a `.` but only looks like one.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis as the text visualizer while debugging show me, this is what result from the use of this RegEx : "…es" I tried with dots in numerique paddle and in the same button as ; on the keyboard but both are not working, I even tried with "," just to see if I was almost blind and see the dot badly.

Comment: The character `…` is not the same as three `.`

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis but ... is compsed by three . so if i tried to match each char on at a time shouldn't it match ?

Comment: @Slayner There are three characters `...` and there's this one `…` - in the second string, you can't select the individual dots. It's a completely different character that only happens to look like three dots. Are you sure you have three dots instead of the single character that *looks* like three?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis okay so this is why the RegEx did not work ? it did not know they were différents type of dots

Comment: @Slayner Yes, if you have the other kind of dot, it's normal that none of the answers would work as they are right now. But most of them can be easily changed to match your use case.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Ho Ok, if i had knew that,it would have been beter so, sorry for all the guys that lost time in there. Do you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

This does not need RegEx:

```
string test = testx.Split(new string[] { "..." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Single(s => !s.StartsWith("(") && !s.EndsWith(")"));
```

This splits the original string by the dots and only returns the part that does not start and end with parentheses.

Comment: I got an error on your methods : "The best overloded method match for 'string.Split(string[],System.StringSplitOptions)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Fixed, the function takes an array of delimiter strings, not one string.

Comment: I tried your solution with a 'string test = (ceci)...es'
I got an error message saying "InvalidOperationException was unhadled by user code " and "the sequence does not contain matching element". So He obviously try to remove them but does not seems to match with what I have.

Comment: If you run this you're still getting an error?  string testx = "(ceci)...es";
            string test = testx.Split(new string[] { "..." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Single(s => !s.StartsWith("(") && !s.EndsWith(")"));
            Console.WriteLine(test);

Comment: @K.Gkinis yes I got the same error it does not match, I don't know why.

Comment: Are you writing in .NET? using System; ?

Comment: @K.Gkinis application is .Net but here it is on a simple cs class, System is one of my using at the top of this class

Answer (score 1):

This is a LINQ solution working in all 3 cases:

```
var res = String.Join("", Char.IsLetter(input.First()) ?
                          input.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsLetter(c)) :
                          input.SkipWhile(c => c != '.')
                               .SkipWhile(c => c == '.')
                               .TakeWhile(c => Char.IsLetter(c)));
```

Comment: with this you skip the dots but you kept the parenthèses and what are Inside ?

Comment: take a look at `Enumerable.SkipWhile`, here if there are any dots in the string the lambda skips all characters before the dots, then skips the dots.

Comment: so this will only work for test1 and not for test2 or 3 because SkipeWhile only remove what is before the dots. So in test2 I will loose what I want to keep.

Comment: it works for test2 too, as there is a conditional operator (`Char.IsLetter(input.First()) ? (linq1) : (linq2) `

Comment: Okay I tried it and the result is just an empty string.

Comment: In which case? It works for all three inputs for me.

Comment: in all case he just return an empty string. I'm guessing this as to do with the fact that a simple replace(".", string.empty) does not remove the "..." part of the string. It's like this is not a "." for him.

Comment: There is no `String.Replace` in this solution, try to use it literally and it should work.

Comment: I know i tried somthing on my side, i tried removing only the dots from the string but he did not match with them. I'm trying to figure why.